# Clarification about Combination problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

50 people consisting of 25 boys and 25 girls are sending a group of 20 people to camp. How many was can 20 people be constructed so that there are is at least 1 girl in the group?

I'm still trying to understand combinations. I believe the answer would just be $25 \choose 1$. Is this correct? The only thing I'm not sure about is how the 19 or less boys would come into play here.

Comment: Hint: It may be easier to think of how many groups consist of no girls.

Answer (score 4):

Let us count the number of groups without any girls: there are $25 \choose 20$ possibilities (just pick 20 boys out of 25).

Let us count the total number of possible groups: here are $50 \choose 20$ possibilities (just pick 20 kids out of 50).

Consequently you have ${50 \choose 20} - {25 \choose 20}$ groups with at least one girl.

Generally when you have to count the number of elements in a set such that *at least 1 element verifies a property* it is easier to count the number of elements such that *0 element verifies the property* and then compute the difference with the total number of elements in your set.

Comment: Thank you! This is so obvious, yet I never made the connection that I can add and subtract these. Sometimes when I am learning new concepts my brain forgets simple things.

Comment: it is normal :) and this is a very classical technique. For example we generally use it to solve the "birthday paradox" in probability https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: ...and is more elegant than my answer, but I'll leave my answer there for posterity ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need "at least 1 girl". From a probability standpoint, P(at least one girl) = 1 - P(no girls)

For combinatorics, that would mean there can be 19 boys and 1 girl, or 18 boys and 2 girls, or ... up to 0 boys and 20 girls.

${25 \choose 19}{25 \choose 1}$ is the number of ways to choose 19 boys from 25 and 1 girl from 25. The total number of ways to choose at least 1 girl would then be:

$${25 \choose 19}{25 \choose 1} + {25 \choose 18}{25 \choose 2} + \ldots + {25 \choose 0}{25 \choose 20}$$

Comment: ...and if you simplify your answer with Vandermonde's indentity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) you get the same result as in my answer ;)

Comment: Yep, so my answer isn't wrong, it's just inelegant. Kudos to you for a beautiful answer :) I voted you up.